# Create XML file in Xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xcode

I need to create code in Swift for iOS device, to create and save a local XML file. It's actually a KML file with waypoints for exporting to Google earth.
I found the API reference here: [API Reference - Class - XMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/xmldocument)
But it lacks an example of how to use these functions. Other examples I find online are all in objective C, so I'm lost how to write the code.

If someone can show simple example of how to create the file and add some keys, childs etc, that would be awesome.

An example of what this KML output file will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Waypoint Name.kml</name>
    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <ListStyle>
        </ListStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <ListStyle>
        </ListStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Waypoint Name</name>
        <description>Description</description>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-114.4379986989632</longitude>
            <latitude>62.47084160066127</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>9.194188445440662e-10</heading>
            <tilt>0</tilt>
            <range>1000.000042077875</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>-114.4435573708376,62.46869255035281,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: `XMLDocument` and related classes are not available for iOS, just macOS.

Comment: [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) might do what you need

Comment: Seems like overkill for what I need.